# How to set scrolling or marquee in autocomplete text in android?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, marquee

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    style="@style/EditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:hint="@string/searchspecial"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

This is my autocomplete code but here I used `marquee` but its not working . Runtime error occurs!

Logcat:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(29075): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView (LOGCAT ERROR)
```

Comment: Can you show us your logcat?

Comment: And also try adding `android:focusable="true"`

Comment: put code in java textView.setSelected(true);

Comment: for example autocomplete i put hint name 'specialization details' not fully show. so i try marquee